# synchronous execution of methods

Tags: node.js, express, synchronization, net-snmp

I have below snmp call in my code, and am executing this in api call and need to get array of values and return it to the client side. but i am facing issue in executing this lines synchronously, my res.json executing first before getting vales from session.subtree

```
    var shelf = new Array();

    function doneCb (error) {
            console.log("donecb");
            console.log("shelf -----",shelf);
    }

    function feedCb (varbinds) {
            console.log("feed cb");
            shelf = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < varbinds.length; i++) {
            if (snmp.isVarbindError (varbinds[i]))
                console.error (snmp.varbindError (varbinds[i]));
            else {
                var temp = varbinds[i].oid.trim(".");
                shelf.push({'id':temp[temp.length-1], 'name':shelfmap[varbinds[i].value.toString()]});
                console.log (varbinds[i].oid + "|" + shelfmap[varbinds[i].value.toString()]);
            }
        }
    }

    router.get('/getShelves/:r',function(req,res){
        shelf = [];
        session.subtree (oid, maxRepetitions, feedCb, doneCb);
        res.json(shelf);
    });
```

since feedcb and donecb are internal methods of net-snmp module i am not able to rewrite the functions to return the values, I tried with sync and async waterfall model, but it is not working as excepted, kinldy someone suggest some way to execute the method synchronously in node JS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to produce the result from inside of `doneCb`. This ensures that all the processing has completed and your `shelf` filled.

Comment: @Thilo, Thanks for your reply, I am not sure how to return the res from doneCb, and also since it is internal method definition I am not able to return the value from donecb to main api method, could you please provide some sample.

Comment: You cannot return the result directly. The caller of your code has to provide a completion callback to you. You call that from within `doneCb`. Alternatively, you can set up a "Promise" to return to your caller that you then "complete" from `doneCb`. There is no shortcut around structuring your code to allow for asynchronous execution.